# Where to place NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute for an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, satellite-assembly

Simple question:

Where should I place `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US" , UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]` for an ASP.NET MVC application?

On the HttpApplication class in Global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes in **AssemblyInfo.cs**

Seems obvious in hindsight.  Thanks.